# I like using ChartJS for it's simplicity, but I can't figure out how to make a bar graph that will graph positive and negative values starting at zero

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

The goal is to make a bar chart that looks like this:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/9783/747489/YXnBVg3j1WhmCoc/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-15%20at%2010.56.58%20PM.png

I can get the line graph no problem, and I haven tried overlaying the graphs yet, the main issue I'm running into is getting a bar graph that starts at 0 and has both a positive and a negative data set graphed at the same time as shown in the attached image.  Any help would be appreciated, right now all I can manage are bar graphs graphed from the bottom of the graph not from the center point (zero).

Comment: any answer on this question?